# Why the distance is never less than 1?

Tags: unity, c#

The distance is 1.07 and changing sometimes at this point the distance is 1.06 or 1.07 more or less this range.

[image: distance]

```
float playertargetdistane = Vector3.Distance(player.position, target.position);

            if (playertargetdistane < 1.06f && startSlow && speed == 1f)
            {
                StartCoroutine(ChangeSpeed(1, 0, 3f));

                startSlow = false;
            }
```

This screenshot show when the player is reaching the target a cube.

[image: Player has reached the target]

It seems to me that both colliders are almost if not touching each other and yet the distance is never less than 1. So I tried to check for less than 1.06 but sometimes it's 1.07 more or less at this time.

If the colliders are so close to each other ho come the distance is never less than 1 ?

Comment: Code should always be shared as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 2):

The Vector3.Distance between two transforms is measured from their centres, not the edges of the colliders. You might have btter luck with [Collider.ClosestPointOnBounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPointOnBounds.html)

Comment: This answer would be even better if it showed how to apply ClosestPointOnBounds to solve this problem.